# Trying to arrange a 2D array in ascending order C#

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to arrange a 2D array in ascending order. This code runs for a 1D array but i'm struggling to implement it for 2D so that it places each row of the array in ascending order.

1D

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] sam = { 4, 7, 2, 0 };

        Array.Sort(sam);
        foreach (int value in sam)
        {
            Console.Write(value);
            Console.Write(' ');
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

2D

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] sam = { 4, 7, 2, 0 }, {4, 6, 2, 0};

            Array.Sort(sam);
            foreach (int value in sam)
            {
                Console.Write(value);
                Console.Write(' ');
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[][] sam = new int[2][];
        sam[0] = new int[] {4, 6, 2, 0};
        sam[1] = new int[] {4, 7, 2, 0};

        foreach(var array in sam)
        {
            Array.Sort(array);
            foreach(var item in array)
                Console.Write(item+" ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
}
```

Here, we are declaring a 2D array and then initializing each array one at a time. Then, we are looping through the **sam** array and then sorting each 1D array within it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions, one solution I'm thinking is using Array of Arrays ([`Jagged Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)).

Let's say, if you have jagged array as defined below

```
    int[][]  numbers2 = new int[][] {
        new int[]{4,5,6}, 
        new int[]{1,2,3}, 
        new int[]{7,8,9}
        ...
    };
```

You can get sorted Jagged array using

```
int[][] sorted = numbers2.Select(x=> string.Join("-", x.ToArray()))
            .OrderBy(x=>x)
            .Select(x=> x.Split('-').Select(int.Parse).ToArray())       
            .ToArray();
```

Another option, let's your input is a 2d array you could do more or less same but output is sorted Jagged array.

```
int[][] sorted_array  = numbers.Cast<int>()     
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / (numbers.GetUpperBound(0) +1))
        .Select(x => string.Join("-", x.Select(v => v.Value)) )
        .OrderBy(x=>x)
        .Select(x=> x.Split('-').Select(int.Parse).ToArray())       
        .ToArray();
```

These are just my options, you will be the best to choose which is right to your solution.

Check this [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z5VFjg)